# Redirecting stdout makes modem unable to connect

Tags: stdout, modem, pppd

I'm running Yocto with busybox on an embedded system with a Telit modem.

If I launch the main program, script A, with

```
./script_A &
```

there's no problem at all and the modem connects on the first try. But when I run

```
./script_A > /dev/null &
```

or any other variant to redirect stdout/in/err, the modem cannot connect and shows AT+CSQ=99,99, which means that the signal is not known or not detectable.

Why can't I redirect stdout?

Comment: What is your script doing?

Comment: @Kusalananda A bunch of GPIO declarations, followed by a while loop: 

`while [ 1 ]
do

eval killall -HUP pppd

eval /path/script_B
status=$?
`
I check status to turn off the modem correctly if script B ends for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a problem with an AT command for the modem. I needed to send AT+WS46=30 instead of AT+WS46=25.

Talk about a weird side effect.